# Inheritance of nested generics / nested generics in abstract class C#

Tags: c#, generics, abstract

I have two abstract classes that can be inherited for explicit usage: A_GUI_Info and A_Info_Data. The GUI_Infos are GUI elements that display data. The Info_Datas are data classes, that transfer specific data to the according GUI_Info.

I want to express the dependency that an explicit GUI_Info has one explicit Info_Data through generics and still allow an inheritance. With other words, I want to avoid that a wrong explicit Info_Data is fed to an explicit GUI_Info. For example, I feed HUD_Info_Data to a Wrist_GUI_Element that does not have the means to represent it. > A kind of type-safety for inherited generics

Example:

```
class HUDInfoData : A_Info_Data
class HUDInfo<HUDInfoData > : A_GUI_Info<A_Info_Data> 
// but the generic cant be inherited like that

class HUDInfo : A_GUI_Info<A_Info_Data>
// doesnt define dependency

class HUDInfo : A_GUI_Info<HUDInfoData >
// also not working
```

Another approach is restrictions by `where T : A_GUI_Info<D> where D : A_Info_Data` But it did not work like that.

The final requirement, that I cant get to work is: I have an instance of the explicit Info and want to handle it in a function, that could also handle all other inherited Infos with their according Datas.

```
public HUD_Info<HUD_Info_Data> obj;

public List<A_GUI_Info<A_Info_Data>> infos;

public void SetConnection(string ID, A_GUI_Info<A_Info_Data> p)
{
    infos.Add(p);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may end up that you need to use this kind of data structure:

```
public abstract class A_GUI_Info<G, D>
    where G : A_Info_Data<G, D>
    where D : A_GUI_Info<G, D>
{
    public G Gui { get; set; }
}

public abstract class A_Info_Data<G, D>
    where G : A_Info_Data<G, D>
    where D : A_GUI_Info<G, D>
{
    public D Data { get; set; }
}
```

It's not overly nice, but it does tie the two derived types to each other.

You would defined them like this:

```
public class HUDInfoData : A_Info_Data<HUDInfoData, HUDInfo>
{
}

public class HUDInfo : A_GUI_Info<HUDInfoData, HUDInfo>
{
}
```

Comment: This answer is not directly the solution to my problem. However wrapping the whole thing and exposing the elements as variables would be a robust solution in many cases.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
abstract class A_Info_Data { ... }
abstract class A_GUI_Info<T> where T: A_Info_Data { ... }
```

And now:

```
class CriticalData: A_Info_Data { ... }
class CriticalGui: A_GUI_Info<CriticalData> { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

The type parameter on the base class only exists on the base class. The more derived class has to define a new type parameter and pipe through the type to the base class's type parameter. This gives you a place to pose more generic constraints.

For example:

```
class HUDInfo<THudInfoData> : A_GUI_Info<THudInfoData> where THudInfoData : A_Info_Data
```

Now, `HUDInfo<>` can take any `HudInfoData` as long as it derives from `A_Info_Data` (or if it *is* `A_Info_Data`). If you wanted to have `HUDExtremelySpecificInfo` which could only take `HUDExtremelySpecificInfoData`, that would look like:

```
class HUDExtremelySpecificInfo<THudInfoData> : A_GUI_Info<THudInfoData>
    where THudInfoData : HUDExtremelySpecificInfoData
```

If you never want to specify the type because you know that it will always be `HUDExtremelySpecificInfoData`, you can also declare either both:

```
class HUDExtremelySpecificInfo<THudInfoData> : A_GUI_Info<THudInfoData>
    where THudInfoData : HUDExtremelySpecificInfoData { .. }

class HUDExtremelySpecificInfo : HUDExtremelySpecificInfo<HUDExtremelySpecificInfoData> { .. }
```

(where you implement the non-generic `HUDExtremelySpecificInfo` in terms of the generic `HUDExtremelySpecificInfo<>`, and can use the generic one if there's a specific even more extremely specific info data subclass that you want to specify)

or just one:

```
class HUDExtremelySpecificInfo : A_GUI_Info<HUDExtremelySpecificInfoData> { .. }
```

Comment: Yes, but then you won't be placing a constraint on the type parameter `THudInfoData` that whatever you pass there has to be `HUDExtremelySpecificInfoData` or a subclass thereof, which I thought was the whole point of the exercise.

Comment: This looks like the right approach. But I want to use the explicit class combination as a function parameter: SetConnection(string ID, GUI_Info<Info_Data> element) But I have problems defining the function generics accordingly, so the function will work with every explicit creation.

Comment: In the method's parameter list, for every time there's a generic type parameter, you have to either fix it in place (`List<string>`) or have a type parameter in the containing type or on the method that you can refer back to (`List<T>`, with `T` defined for the method or on the type itself).

Comment: But this is sitll not making sense: `class HUDExtremelySpecificInfo<THudInfoData> : A_GUI_Info<THudInfoData>
    where THudInfoData : HUDExtremelySpecificInfoData`. Why not simply `class HUDExtremelySpecificInfo : A_GUI_Info<ExtremelySpecificInfoData>`? That was my original comment. I'm failing to see why `HUDExtremelySpecificInfo` has to be generic at all.

Comment: It does make sense because the question seemed to imply that there can be tons of subclasses. If there are two or three even more specific infodata classes, you can pass either one as the generic argument. If there's only one, you don't strictly need anything else than the bottom one. That's why I edited my answer to mention both.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for giving constructive answers. What I try here is not working like preferred (pbbly not possible at all). This is what I came up with:

```
// abstract definitions
public abstract class AInfo
{
    public abstract void SetData(AInfoData data);
}
public abstract class AInfoData

// explicit definitions
public class WristInfo : AInfo
{
    public override void SetData(AInfoData data)
    {
        Data_Info_Wrist d = (Data_Info_Wrist)data; // cast to use
    }
}
public class Data_Info_Wrist : AInfoData

// runtime usage
public AInfo instance; (WristInfo)

public void Setup(AInfo info) { }
```

For Unity workflow I require the explicit class to be non-generic. So this workaround is possibly the best solution. The drawback: The desired type-safety is not given here.